# Site Health says I'm running an older version of PHP even after I upgraded to 7.4.4

Tags: php

There is an error that displays in "Site Health" that says that I'm running an older version of PHP. After upgrading to the latest, I'm still getting the error. Is there something I missed?

[image]

Comment: What OS are you running? Linux? Windows? Mac?

Comment: I run 3 versions of php and it is important for apache or nginx to include proper handlers for specific versions. Did you restart your http server after upgrade? Not knowing your server environment makes it more difficult to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @simongcc Windows

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom Sorry for the lack of details. Basically, I host the WP site on DigitalOcean on Ubuntu 18.0.4. I restarted Apache after upgrading the PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you could try to confirm

- create a php file with `phpinfo()` to see what version it is running
- then go to httpd.conf to locate `LoadModule php7_module ...` to find out which file it is calling

Sometimes `LoadModule` is put inside httpd.config, sometimes maybe in include file instead but you could find the information inside this config file. Because it depends what package are you using. It might be XAMPP, LAMP or standalone installation. But the concept and configuration are almost the same.

If you upgrade, it is most likely that you haven't updated the config file.

Comment: The `phpinfo()` page says I'm running `PHP Version 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3` As for `httpd.conf` it says it's located at `/etc/apache2` but I can't seem to locate it although I do see `apache2.conf`

Comment: Then it is the reason. There will be a few copies of `httpd.conf` because by default. It will have a default copy for you to refer which is not something you are looking for. For Windows, you may install this [file locator](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite/download/) which I have used for many years. Easier to find the file. Once you locate the file. Then things is very easy. Just correct the path inside and load the most updated php module. BTW, are you using subsystem for apache? or you are using native Windows environment to install?

Comment: For config file location, you may also refer to [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61303/location-of-httpd-conf-file) which belongs to server questions.